# Three.js - Bigger bounding box after rotation

Tags: javascript, three.js

So I am having this code:

```
computeCarBoundingBox(mesh);

mesh.rotation.x = this.rotationVal[ 0 ];
mesh.rotation.y = this.rotationVal[ 1 ];
mesh.rotation.z = this.rotationVal[ 2 ];
```

Where I try to compute a bounding box for a mesh, if I compute it after rotation look like this:
[image: First pic]

If I compute it after the rotation look like this:
[image: Second]

[image: second picture from the top]

My compute bounding box function is this:

```
function computeCarBoundingBox(mesh){

        var box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(mesh);

        var boundingBoxHelper = new THREE.Box3Helper( box, 0xffff00 );  
        scope.carBoundingBox =boundingBoxHelper;
        scene.add(scope.carBoundingBox);
        console.log(box.min); // x, y, and z are all Infinity.
        console.log(box.max); // x, y, and z are all -Infinity.


}
```

---

I do have a geometry.  This is a part of my code :

```
this.loadCar = function ( carsVector,carName,roadName ) {
    if(carName=='veyron')
    {
        var index = 0;

    }
    else if(carName=='F50')
    {
        var index = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        var index = 2;
    }
    console.log("Selected car name:"+carName);
    var carLoader = new THREE.BinaryLoader();
    carLoader.load( carsVector[Object.keys(carsVector)[index]].url, function( geometry ) { 

        geometry.sortFacesByMaterialIndex();
        console.log("url--->"+carsVector[Object.keys(carsVector)[index]].url);


        var materials = [];
        this.scaleVal = carsVector[ Object.keys(carsVector)[index] ].scale * 1;
        if(roadName =='road01'){
            this.positionVal = carsVector[ Object.keys(carsVector)[index] ].position_r1;
        }
        else if(roadName=='road02'){
            this.positionVal = carsVector[ Object.keys(carsVector)[index] ].position_r2;
        }

        this.rotationVal = carsVector[ Object.keys(carsVector)[index] ].init_rotation;


        for ( var i in carsVector[ Object.keys(carsVector)[index] ].materialsMap ) {
            materials[ i ] = carsVector[ Object.keys(carsVector)[index] ].materialsMap[ i ];
        }
        createObject(geometry,materials);
    });

    return scope.carMesh;

}


    // internal helper methods

function createObject ( geometry, materials ) {

    scope.carGeometry = geometry;
    scope.carMaterials = materials;

    createCar();

};

function createCar () {
    console.log("CREATE CARRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR");
    if ( scope.carGeometry ) {
        var carMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( scope.carMaterials );
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( scope.carGeometry, carMaterial );



        mesh.scale.x = mesh.scale.y = mesh.scale.z = this.scaleVal;

        mesh.position.set( this.positionVal[0], this.positionVal[1], this.positionVal[2]);



                mesh.rotation.x = this.rotationVal[ 0 ];
                mesh.rotation.y = this.rotationVal[ 1 ];
                mesh.rotation.z = this.rotationVal[ 2 ];
                this.carMesh = mesh;

                //
                    computeCarBoundingBox(mesh);

                console.log("This car mesh"+this.carMesh);
                addShadows();
                scene.add(this.carMesh);

                //this.carBoundingBox.rotation.x =this.r[0];
                //this.carBoundingBox.rotation.y = this.r[1];
                //this.carBoundingBox.rotation.z = this.r[2];
                //scene.add( this.carBoundingBox );
    }

    if ( scope.callback ) {

        scope.callback(this.carMesh);

    }

}
```

Comment: After calling [`.setFromObject()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/math/Box3.setFromObject), you get the world-axis-aligned bounding box of an object.

Answer (score 1):

These are the methods I'm using in my project where I add the bounding boxes after rotation. If you don't rotate first you don't need the adjustRelativeTo step see e.g. https://codepen.io/seppl2019/pen/zgJVKM
[image]

```
class ChildPart {
  constructor(mesh) {
    this.mesh=mesh;
    this.boxwire=null;
  }

  // add my bounding box wire to the given mesh
  addBoundingBoxWire(toMesh) {
    var boxwire = new THREE.BoxHelper(this.mesh, 0xff8000);
    this.boxwire=boxwire;
    ChildPart.adjustRelativeTo(boxwire,toMesh);
    toMesh.add(boxwire);
  }

  static adjustRelativeTo(mesh,toMesh) {
    //logSelected("adjusting toMesh",toMesh);
    //logSelected("beforeAdjust",this.mesh);
    toMesh.updateMatrixWorld(); // important !
    mesh.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().getInverse(toMesh.matrixWorld));
    //logSelected("afterAdjust",this.mesh);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I run into this problem recently. Thanks to @Wolfgang Fahl 's resolution.
Tt’s the right direction, but when I was doing it, I found something was wrong.
When the mesh have rotation effection. the box is still bigger than original one.
So you need to remove rotation before create BoxHelper, then add rotation back.

```
static adjustRelativeTo(mesh, toMesh) {
  toMesh.updateMatrixWorld(); // important !
  mesh.applyMatrix4(new THREE.Matrix4().copy( toMesh.matrixWorld ).invert());
}

addBoundingBox(mesh, toMesh) {
  // remove rotation
  let rotate = mesh.rotation.clone();      
  mesh.rotation.set(0, 0 , 0);

  let box = new THREE.BoxHelper( mesh, 0xffff00);

  // apply to parent matrix
  adjustRelativeTo(box, toMesh);   
  toMesh.add(box);

  // 然后再把旋转加上            
  mesh.rotation.set(rotate.x, rotate.y, rotate.z);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how [`.setFromObject()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/math/Box3.setFromObject) works, when object is wide and when you rotate it, its box will be bigger, as it's world-axis-aligned:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 5, 5);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.75);
light.position.set(-10, 10, -10);
scene.add(light);
scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.25));

scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper(10, 10));

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(2, 1, 3);
geometry.translate(0, 0.5, 0);

var mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
  color: "gray"
}));
mesh1.position.x = -2.5;
scene.add(mesh1);

var mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
  color: "aqua"
}));
mesh2.position.x = 2.5;
mesh2.rotation.y = THREE.Math.degToRad(45);
scene.add(mesh2);

var bbox1 = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(mesh1);
var bbox2 = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(mesh2);

var bhelp1 = new THREE.Box3Helper(bbox1, 0xffff00);
scene.add(bhelp1);
var bhelp2 = new THREE.Box3Helper(bbox2, 0xff00ff);
scene.add(bhelp2);

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/93/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: So I will compute it before, but it's there any way of updating the bounding box to follow the car when I move it?

Comment: @IoanaB The bounding box applies to the geometry. If you want to see how it applies to the mesh, you need to apply the mesh's world matrix.

Answer (score -1):

Alright I have two theories, and no certain answer. sorry!

1) It is possible for meshes to be without geometry. Does your mesh have a geometry? If not the code [called from setFromObject](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/e6c13503ac9a467f78bfe39f7a2c8fe4219308ec/src/math/Box3.js#L219) will fail. (expandByPoint will never be called and min and max will remain at Infinity since the previous makeEmpty-call).

2) Seeing how deeply dependent that recursive "expandByOject" code is on scope and `this`, I would try adding parenthesis to your new-operator `var box = (new THREE.Box3()).setFromObject(mesh);` It's a bit of a shot in the dark, but perhaps the scope is never properly set.

Sorry for not taking the time and testing things out first.

Comment: I posted almost all the code where I am creating the mesh. Hope you can help me

Comment: Aha, could this be a async pitfall perhaps? BinaryLoader.load is a async function, meaning it's slow and the callback `function( geometry ) { ...` will trigger some time in the future. You have to be absolutely sure the mesh exists before you create the BoundingBox. Just like you check `if ( scope.carGeometry  ) {` you should probably check the mesh in computeCarBoundingBox as well.  (A console log might lie to you because it shows the "live" object - if the mesh exists a second later the log will show it. I wish I could take my time and test it, but I also have to choose my battles. Sorry!